# How to deploy a docker container from Azure function app?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions, azure-functions-docker

I want to programmatically deploy a new docker container on demand from an existing image from an azure function app (e.g. from a cosmodb trigger).  Can someone provide some guidance?   I'm having difficulty finding any documentation as all my searches bring up running an azure function within a container, which isn't what I'm trying to do.

**edit further clarification**
in my use case, i am using a cosmosdb trigger in a function app.  When that cosmosdb collection gets a new record, I extract a string from that record, and then pass that string as a run parameter to dynamically create a new docker container from an existing ACR image.

I am thinking I'll have to use powershell within the function app to do this, I was hoping there would be a C# solution.

Comment: What do you mean by deploying a docker container from the Azure function app? deploy the container inside the function or deploy the function from the image?

Comment: There is an azure container instances (ACI) connector in logic apps - which might be an option if your workflow is fairly simple. Otherwise, you might have to look into some of the sdks and configure it yourself.

Comment: @CharlesXu I modified the question to be a bit more specific

Comment: It seems you can create a trigger via C# that create an ACI with the image from ACR. I think it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an Azure devops pipeline to deploy your new container. Then trigger the running of the pipeline from your function app.